# Migration file failed Knexjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, objection.js

I'm not sure what is the problem with migration. I'm using knex to connect sqlite3 DB. I'm totally new to this.

Created table in migration file and then added a column in table using separate migration. But that file failed.

[image]

Logs shown above and I didn't diagnose why it's getting failed.

Migration for table creation is

```
import { Knex } from 'knex';
import { Bag } from '../../src/models';

    export const up = (knex: Knex): Promise<void> =>
      knex.schema.createTable(Bag.tableName, (table: Knex.TableBuilder) => {
        table.increments();
        table.timestamps();
        table.integer('volume');
      });
    
    export const down = (knex: Knex): Promise<void> =>
      knex.schema.dropTable(Bag.tableName);
```

Migration for adding column is

```
import { Knex } from 'knex';
import { Bag } from '../../src/models';

    export const up = (knex: Knex): Promise<void> =>
      knex.schema.alterTable(Bag.tableName, (table: Knex.TableBuilder) => {
        table.string('title');
      });
    
    export const down = (knex: Knex): Promise<void> =>
      knex.schema.alterTable(Bag.tableName, (table: Knex.TableBuilder) => {
        table.dropColumn('title');
      });
```

NOTE: I tried adding column in table creation migration but it also fails and gave me error.

[image]

Also when command to show completed migrations. It listed all migrations including new addedColumn one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an answer for this, why it's getting failed. After trying different methods, my problem was solved by making a new migration before running any migration.

This solved my problem. Although, it's not a solution but it solved my problem.